# "Loss is NaN" error in Keras, how to debug?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I know there are other questions here with the "Loss is NaN", but I'm working with example code provided by François Chollet (author of Keras), what is supposed to be the simplest possible example. I think my issue may be different than what other people are experiencing.

Mostly I think I'd like to know what I can do with this API to burrow down and figure out where the problem is occurring.

Here is the code. With a couple of minor edits, it's directly out of "Deep Learning with Python" by Chollet.

```
import os
os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "plaidml.keras.backend"

from keras.datasets import mnist
(train_images,train_labels),(test_images,test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

from keras import models
from keras import layers

network = models.Sequential()
network.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(28 * 28,), name="layer1"))
network.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', name="layer2"))

network.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

train_images = train_images.reshape((60000, 28 * 28))
train_images = train_images.astype('float32') / 255

test_images = test_images.reshape((10000, 28 * 28))
test_images = test_images.astype('float32')/255

from keras.utils import to_categorical
train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels)
test_labels = to_categorical(test_labels)

network.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5, batch_size=128)

test_loss, test_acc = network.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)

print('Accuracy: ', test_acc)
print('Loss: ', test_loss)
```

I suspect the problem may be with the back end (the first two lines).

The symptom is that all I ever see when the net is training is "loss: nan" and accuracy numbers of 0.0987.

I have read other threads with this error, and they suggest changing some of the parameters or methods of optimizer. For instance I have tried this, based on other threads I read:

```
from keras import optimizers
opt = optimizers.Adam(1e-2)

network.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

It does not change the symptom. And it doesn't matter what argument I put into the initializer, I've tried values from 0.01 down to 1e-8. Same symptoms.

I am running on a Macbook Air. It does not have a Nvidia GPU so it can't run the CUDA library that Keras uses for acceleration. Instead I installed OpenCL and PlaidML, following suggestions of articles I found online, and added those initial two lines to the script.

I am very suspicious that there is something wrong with the setup of PlaidML, but it passes what tests they provide with the installer, and I don't see any warnings or error messages associated with the graphics card.

If it's not that, I don't know what it could be.

And at any rate, as a newbie to deep learning, to Keras, and still relatively inexperienced in Python, I am at a complete loss for what I can do to try to dig down into what's happening here. Does Keras give me any debugging tools?

Comment: I ran your code as it is and it ran flawlessly. I think it is your environment that is causing an issue and hence I would recommend you to use free online resources such as 'google colab' or 'Kaggle'.

Answer (score 0):

Over the last few days I've learned some relevant things.

- This is a known issue with PlaidML, apparently still unresolved. [Here](https://github.com/plaidml/plaidml/issues/168) is the discussion at github.
- While I read in many places that Tensorflow will only work on an Nvidia GPU, I found [at the Intel website](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-optimization-for-tensorflow-installation-guide.html) that Tensorflow will work with the Mac Intel CPU.
- The pip install commands I found here and there for Tensorflow did not work for me, but conda will work: "conda install tensorflow" or "conda install tensorflow -c anaconda"
- Since I now have both Tensorflow Keras and PlaidML Keras installed, I can import with either "from tensorflow.keras import XXX" or "from keras import XXX" to choose the CPU or GPU version. That's useful.

Not yet investigated: According to many websites, if I have a Thunderbolt 3 port (one Mac does, one does not), it is possible to add an external Nvidia eGPU to a Mac. Whether it will work is unknown. Gamer discussion boards seem to say it doesn't work for their purposes, but Keras-related websites say that Tensorflow will use an eGPU just fine.

At any rate, I can proceed with my projects using tensorflow.keras on the CPU. It's not ideal but it works. On the test code above I was seeing about 100 μs/sample, 6 s/epoch.

Bottom line for people experiencing PlaidML-Keras issues: It's a universal issue. PlaidML is broken for a lot of GPUs. For now use Tensorflow on the Intel CPU, and keep your eye on [Issue #168](https://github.com/plaidml/plaidml/issues/168) to watch for a fix.